# How trigger to save post when updating post meta

Tags: post-meta, wp-update-post

I have very confused situation. I have added posts and all posts metas from one website db to another one, everything is fine, images, title, description of posts are there.

But post metas are not showing on webpage(img1), although they are exists when I go to post edit page in wp-admin(img2), I can see the post data , but they are not showing until I click to `'Update'` button myself.

After that all post data is showing.(img3,img4)

Posts are to much (about 4000 recipes) , so I can't do it manually, it will take a long time.

So I need something to trigger every post updating automatically.

I have tried to update post meta, but it doesn't work, it still have to update post manually.

```
$metas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
foreach($metas as $meta_key => $meta_value){
  foreach( $meta_value as $val ){
    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $meta_key, $val);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

**IMG1**
[image: img1]

**IMG2**
[image: img2]

**IMG3**
[image: img3]

**IMG4**
[image: img4]

Comment: I don't understand "I can see the post data , but they are not showing". where are they not showing ? in the admin edit page ?

Comment: I can see the post data in admin page, but it doesn't show in webpage, untillI click the update button from admin

Comment: Are you using advanced custom fields or something similar? Do you use `get_field` to retrieve the field values or `get_post_meta`?

Comment: Are you using some sort of caching plugin?

Comment: @janh2 yes I am using `acf` plugin for some post meta data, I am checking the meta data by getting fileds with `get_post_meta` and all data is there.

Comment: @JacobPeattie no , I am not using cache plugin

Comment: Mh. ACF's `get_field()` doesn't work unless you've added the field references as well (e.g. `myfield` = `myvalue`, `_myfield` = `field_26ae812...`), but that shouldn't matter if you're using `get_post_meta` to retrieve the data in the frontend.

Comment: @janh2 thanks, the problem was because of ACF field names, I changed the names with keys and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this to insert posts with ACF/postmeta data successfully, but please test it on a development site before deploying live, there might be some terrible assumptions. Generally, it assumes that you only have each name once, that is "myfield" doesn't exist in two field groups with different meanings.

```
$mycustomvalue = 123;
$f_mycustomfield = get_acf_key_by_name("mycustomfield");
update_post_meta( $postid, "mycustomfield", $mycustomvalue );
update_post_meta( $postid, "_mycustomfield", $f_mycustomfield["key"] );


function load_acf_names2key() {
    global $acf_names2key;
    $acf_names2key = array();
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'acf',
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order title',
        'order'         => 'asc',
        'suppress_filters' => false,
    ));
    foreach($posts as $fieldgroup) {
        $fields = get_post_meta( $fieldgroup->ID );
        foreach($fields as $fieldkey => $fieldmeta) {
            if(substr($fieldkey, 0, 6) == "field_") {
                $field = get_post_meta( $fieldgroup->ID, $fieldkey);
                foreach($field as $subfield) {
                    if(!array_key_exists($subfield["name"], $acf_names2key)) $acf_names2key[ $subfield["name"] ] = array();
                    $subfield[ "group" ] = $fieldgroup->post_name;
                    array_push( $acf_names2key[ $subfield["name"] ], $subfield );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function get_acf_key_by_name($name, $options = array()) {
    global $acf_names2key;
    if(!$acf_names2key || !is_array($acf_names2key) || count($acf_names2key) == 0) {
        load_acf_names2key();
    }
    if(!array_key_exists($name, $acf_names2key))
        return false;
    foreach($acf_names2key[ $name ] as $possible) {
        foreach($options as $key => $val) {
            if(preg_match("!^/.*/i?$!", $val)) {
                if(!preg_match($val, $possible[ $key ])) {
                    continue 2;
                }
            }
            else if($possible[ $key ] != $val) {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        # no options? this will return the first one
        # has options? will return the first item that
        #     satisfies all options
        return $possible;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's been quite a while since I wrote this and memory fails me what exactly I wanted to do with those $options that can be passed to `get_acf_key_by_name` (or if I just copy pasted that code from somewhere), but it always worked for me.
I haven't tried to work with repeater fields, so that might be a challenge, but give it a try.